# How to load a downloaded file into a NSData variable

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

for my app, I download a file from internet that contains XML and must be parsed.
The problem I am having is: once the file is downloaded I try to load its content into a NSData variable so I can call the parsing function but I am not getting the expected result.

So the procedure goes like this:

1. I download the file using URLSession (this is correct because I have opened the file manually and verified its content is valid)

   let task = downloadsSession.downloadTask(with: lobj_Request as URLRequest)

   task.resume()
2. The delegate method didFinishDownloadingToURL is triggered and I use it to attempt loading the content of the file into a NSData variable

   let xmlData = NSData(contentsOf: location.absoluteURL)
3. I print the content of xmlData and instead of getting the xml I get something like this:

[Xcode output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKHDI.png)

So I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Any hint, help or advice will be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to use NSData at all? I would suggest to use string directly:

```
class del : NSObject, URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        let result = try? String(contentsOf: location)
        if let result = result {
            print (result)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in the end this could en up downloading the url twice ;) you already have downloaded the data AND if it wasn't cached, the delegate could block a long time because of the synchronous call to 'contentsOf: location'

Comment: @Daij: No, check the documentation: `location` is l local temporary file. Nevertheless, you're right with doing the 'real' work in an extra tread, see doc again: 'If you choose to open the file for reading, you should do the actual reading in another thread to avoid blocking the delegate queue.'

Answer (score 0):

you see the raw bytes of the NSData - you expect to see the 'decoded string content' that the raw bytes represent.

so the xmlData might be a string of numbers, each being a byte:
 `7402874 243721 2342111 2342342 234234`

the represented string of that is assembled from the characters represented:
 `let xmlString = String(WithData:xmlData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)`

---

**put that into the session's task completion block - don't try to go with the delegate of the session.**

Comment: Yes, but don't use NSData when you want a string, because this would double the memory impact.